# How did I earn my Saint Lucia hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

I am now sporting the very latest in casual Christmas headgear, in the form of a Saint Lucia hat. It's my best Christmas present so far.

But how did I earn it, please? I have turned hats on, and it seems that I can see that what I have earnt, but there's nothing telling me what each hat means, or what trouser-wettingly brilliant act on my part made it mine.

And there's no [hats] tag on meta!

Comment: Damn time zones... I have about 4.5 hours to go....

Comment: Oh wait never mind :D

Comment: Please see the "Leeway on date-based hats" section of [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/1438)

Comment: My best Christmas present was getting to 1k before the end of the year, my *second best* Christmas present so far is my shiny **Imitation Crab** hat ;).

Comment: How can you find out what you did to earn a secret hat?

Comment: "trouser-wettingly brilliant act" (Y)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The [Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com) page explains how the Saint Lucia hat (and others) is earned:

> Vote on December 15th.

So all you need to do to earn it is cast a vote on the 15th. There are secret hats, and how to earn them is not revealed on that page.

Comment: Ah, interesting... not least because I haven't actually voted yet today! (Don't tell anyone. I like my hat too much.)

Comment: I would be curious if anyone has figured out how the Chameleon hat is earned.

Comment: Looks as though in the last hour you've commented on an answer that's now been deleted, and you've also posted a really long comment. I'm guessing it's the first one (based on the name).

Comment: @vcsjones I logged into a SE which I hadn't logged into in a while and I received chameleon hat for all the SE site accounts.

Comment: @vcsjones chameleon hat for changing hats? or modifying hat style / position? or change to profile pic? that's all I did and I got it.

Comment: [Lucia is on the 13th not on the 15th!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280324/st-lucia-hat-awarded-on-the-wrong-date)

Comment: I was about to write exactly the same: Saint Lucia is on the 13rd :D

Answer (score 15):

You already got the direct link in another answer, but here is how to navigate to it from the UI:

1. Click on the snowflake in the titlebar, next to the icons that show new messages and rep changes.
2. In the pulldown that is shown, click on the white "WINTER BASH" label on light blue background.

Or in pictures, click in the area circled red:

[image]

This will show you a list of all (officially) available hats, with a short summary of how to earn each one.

Comment: I'll just say it was relatively hard to figure out how to *wear* my hat. But hey, I saw a part of stack exchange I've never seen before - the "Apps" section.

Comment: I only had to click on one of the hats, and it showed me a dialog where I could choose to wear the hat. My biggest problem is that the hats look kind of silly if you don't have a head. ;)

Comment: Tip: It's spelled _Joga Bonito_ and not _Joga Bounito_. Unless Portuguese wasn't the intended language there (which I doubt, as the hat is linked to _football_).

Answer (score 7):

You can find it in the [Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) site.
Also you can find it in the Hats pop-up, as shown in image.

[image: Hats]

Comment: I see you have the Star Trek themed secret hats too. I thought it had something to do with my avatar, but I guess not.