# St. Lucia hat awarded on the wrong date

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2014

> Her feast day, known as Saint Lucy's Day, is celebrated in the West on 13 December <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

I was getting a hat for voting on the 15th... Is that a bug?

Comment: Depending on the dimension, it is currently December 13th.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How did I earn my hat?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280260/how-did-i-earn-my-hat)

Comment: It is not a duplicate - I did not ask HOW I got my hat, but if getting a LUCIA hat on the 15th when Lucia is on the 13th is a bug or not.

Comment: A festival of light for someone who had their eyes gouged out. People are very strange.

Comment: Many Catholic fests are like that. Halloween anyone?

Comment: @mplungjan Halloween is not Catholic, it is an ancient Irish festival.

Comment: Whatever... http://www.cracked.com/article_16509_the-8-most-bizarre-patron-saints.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The hat is awarded for the 15th, for better or worse.

Americans were never that good with European holidays, but my guess is that in this case it was shifted over by a few days to coincide with the start of the Winter Bash, rather than have to deal with all the questions about how the system knew they had voted before the Bash had even started, never mind all the whining and pleading from those hat hunters that had not voted on the 13th but now want a developer to give them a time machine Hail Mary.

Comment: Ah, then we will ask Halloween to be on the 1st of November because that is the start of a new month ;)

Comment: Those darn Americans

Comment: @bluefeet: in the US a neighbour consistently kept talking about how I was Danish. So easy to confuse with Dutch, after all. It's all so very far away..

Comment: I AM Danish, living in The Hague ;)

Comment: Well, you should be more sensible about naming your holidays. We never forget what date the 4th of July or Cinco de Mayo fall on. ;p

Comment: @mplungjan: You'll be Dutch then, in his book. Whatever you tell him.

Comment: Geen probleem :)

Comment: @mplungjan: Ingen problem, mener du? (Sorry, Norwegian, didn't want to use Google Translate but you Danes should have no problem with that anyway. I think the Danish spelling is but a few characters difference).

Comment: [Right on all counts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245276/1438)

Comment: _Du mener: intet problem?_ :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard I know plenty of Americans who don't know when Cinco de Mayo is.

Comment: @Degustaf Those must be the fools who studied French in high school instead of Spanish! (I studied French in high school instead of Spanish.)

Comment: Sarcastically: `Is that the 5 jars of mayonnaise celebration?`

Comment: Or טו בשבט‎ or תשעה באב for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

See [Why is the hat called St. Lucia?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245255/why-is-the-hat-called-st-lucia) over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The accepted answer seems to be from the admin that created the St. Lucia hat.

Comment: With a name like Ericson he should have known better ;)

Comment: That same employee [already commented on my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280324/st-lucia-hat-awarded-on-the-wrong-date/280325?noredirect=1#comment130052_280325).